# Fetching technical indicators from yahoo api

Tags: capital-gain, yahoo-finance, technical-analysis

I am trying to get RSI indicator from yahoo finance api.

so far I can get quote in CSV format, but there seems no api for specific indicator such as RSI.

Anyone knows how ?

thanks

Comment: is there any reason why you don't just calculate them? the benefit of that is that you could change the parameters if you ever wanted to, this is especially useful for defining which MA is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still working on exact answer to question....for now:

> ***(BONUS)*** Here is how to pull a graphical chart with the required data:
>
> ```
> Technical Indicators 2
>
>     Here you can declare the second part of technical indicators.
>
>     If you have more than one seperate them with ",".
>
>     This part is valid for the following indicators:
>
>     MACD 
>     MFI 
>     ROC 
>     RSI 
>     Slow_Stoch 
>     Fast_Stoch 
>     Vol_MA 
>     W_R
>
>     **Add to the end of the URL "&a=" and for each indicator the tag.**
> ```
>
> Therefore:
>
> ```
> http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=l&p=m50,e200,v&a=r14
> ```
>
> As r14 = the indicator for RSI.  The above pull would pull Google,
>   6months, line chart, linear, large, with a 50 day moving average, a
>   200 day exponential moving average, volume, and followed up with RSI.
>
> Reference Link:
>
> [Finance Yahoo! API's](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/miscapiImageDownload)

Comment: thanks for reply, but this gives result as an image, i need data for example, a value of RSI so that i can work with it.

Comment: Can you show me what you are pulling for data as of now in CSV format? I'm thinking the only way is to use the data and calculate the EMA's then calculate the RSI.  I don't see a 'pull' option in the API for RSI in CSV format.

Comment: adding r14 into the string such as:
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EDJI,GOOG&f=nsl1opr14&e=.csv 
doesn't work - I tested it

Comment: currently i can only download quote data as @MD-Tech did which doesn't contain RSI column. I can, however, manually calculate with a java program  i made, but result is not so good as I found discrepancies comparing to yahoo result. Too bad, i can't find a way to pull RSI data

Comment: Yeah a lot of calculations from xxxxx.finance.com etc. have different calculations than what you might find elsewhere.  Probably the only way thought but as long as you test vs different sources the numbers should be close.